# What is the difference between fs.checkpoint.dir and dfs.name.dir?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Mainly dfs.name.dir property is use to store the fsimage of namenode to the particular location for backup and fs.checkpoint.dir property is the location where the fsimage merge. This is little bit confuse to me. Can any one explain me in detail.

Answer (score 3):

`dfs.name.dir` is the place where the namenode stores the fsimage and editlogs in disk. This is a mandatory location. Without this location, a hadoop cluster will not start. This will be located in the namenode host.

`fs.checkpoint.dir` is the directory on the local filesystem where the DFS secondary name node should store the temporary images to merge. If this is a comma-delimited list of directories then the image is replicated in all of the directories for redundancy. This is not a mandatory location. Without this directory also the hadoop cluster will start. This will be located in the secondary namenode host.

The fsimage and edit logs are merged periodically through secondary namenode. If secondary is not present, the merging of fsimage and editlogs will happen only at the time of namenode restart.

The explanation of secondary namenode is available in this [blog post](https://amalgjose.wordpress.com/2013/08/09/secondary-namenode/)

Answer (score 2):

**dfs.name.dir**

It was deprecated and replaced by **dfs.namenode.name.dir**. It determines where on the local file system the DFS name node should store the name table(fsimage). If this is a comma-delimited list of directories then the name table is replicated in all of the directories, for redundancy.

This property is used by Name Node.

**fs.checkpoint.dir**

It is deprecated and replaced by **dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir**. It determines where on the local file system the DFS secondary name node should store the temporary images to merge. If this is a comma-delimited list of directories then the image is replicated in all of the directories for redundancy.

The secondary Name Node merges the fsimage and the edits log files periodically and keeps edits log size within a limit. It is usually run on a different machine than the primary Name Node since its memory requirements are on the same order as the primary Name Node.

The secondary Name Node stores the latest checkpoint in a directory which is structured the same way as the primary Name Node’s directory. So that the check pointed image is always ready to be read by the primary Name Node if necessary.

The NameNode will upload the checkpoint from the **dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir** directory and then save it to the NameNode directory(s) set in **dfs.namenode.name.dir**.

The NameNode will fail if a legal image is contained in **dfs.namenode.name.dir**.

The NameNode verifies that the image in **dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir** is consistent, but does not modify it in any way.

Refer to [HDFS user guide](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html)